# Jasypt not able to decrypt password from system environment variable with Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jasypt

I have jasypt password and the encrypted password defined in application.yml like this:

```
jasypt:
  encryptor:
    password: ${secretKey}

spring:
   datasource: 
       password: ENC(${password})
```

And using @Value for it:

```
@Value("${spring.datasource.password}")
private String springPassword;
```

I have defined both secretKey and password in my environment variable. But when I start this spring boot application, it throws error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.cache.Cache$ValueRetrievalException: Value for key 'spring.datasource.password' could not be loaded using 'com.ulisesbocchio.jasyptspringboot.caching.CachingDelegateEncryptablePropertySource$$Lambda$209/172678484@5ae15'
```

If I hardcode both of the keys, than it's working fine.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I had similar issue. The reason in my case was that I had jasypt-1.9.2.jar and jasypt-1.9.4.jar on the class path.

jasypt-1.9.4.jar came as dependency from jasypt-spring-boot 2.1.1.
jasypt-1.9.2.jar came as dependency from wss4j-ws-security-common 2.2.2.

Changing to jasypt-spring-boot 2.1.0 solved the issue in my case.

Comment: I was using maven as dependency handler and there was no dependency overlapping..

Comment: Maven can't resolve the dependency conflict as jasypt 1.9.2 has groupId='org.jasypt' and jasypt 1.9.4 has groupId='com.melloware'. But classes inside are in the same packages (org.jasypt...) and have the same names.

Answer (score 2):

I know it's too late but still. For me passing the ENC() method as part of environmental variable worked.

```
jasypt:
  encryptor:
    password: ${secretKey}

spring:
   datasource: 
       password: ${PASSWORD}
```

while setting environmental variable

```
export PASSWORD=ENC(yourPassword)
```